# why doing loops breaks my program?

Tags: anchor

i have this method in my program:

```
    pub fn create_game(ctx: Context<CreateGame>, players: Vec<Pubkey>, items_by_line: u8, lines: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let mut board = [];
        
        for i in 0..(items_by_line * lines){
            board[i as usize] = Bubble { player: i % players.len() as u8, amount: 1 }
        }
        
        let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;
        game.board = board.to_vec();
        game.players = players;
        Ok(())
    }
```

it trows this error:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5054:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5013:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

if i comment out the for loop the instruction success.
Can someone helpme understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like my problem is related to the way i'm initializing the board variable or the way i was trying to set the values into the array, i changed to be a Vec and the assignation by index to a push, and it works.

my code after changes:

```
    pub fn create_game(ctx: Context<CreateGame>, players: Vec<Pubkey>, items_by_line: u8, lines: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let mut board: Vec<Bubble> = [].to_vec();
        
        for i in 0..(items_by_line * lines){
            board.push(Bubble { player: i % players.len() as u8, amount: 1 })
        }
        
        let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;
        game.board = board;
        game.players = players;
        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

an additional point, if you need further context on anchor errors you cna check in the program logs. those are saved in the project root in the `.anchor/program-logs` folder. you should be able to find more informations on error like that